# Loading js script like google analytics does and then run a function

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to modify a js snippet that creates a js tag, it currently uses `document.write` which breaks the page removing all the existing DOM elements. I wanted to use something like google analytics does, my current code looks something like this:

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.type = 'text/javascript';
scr.async = true;
scr.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.myurl.com/myscript.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(scr, s);

stuff.somefunc({
    userID: '2312312'
});
```

My problem is that `stuff` is obviously undefined, I want to avoid using some `onload` methods since I tried it in the past and had problems in some browsers. I tried to figure out how google analytics do it but my js skills are not that great. Here's the analytics sample:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
     window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = 'ga';
     window['ga'] = window['ga'] || function () {
         (window['ga'].q = window['ga'].q || []).push(arguments)
     }, window['ga'].l = 1 * new Date();
     a = document.createElement('script'),
     m = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     a.async = 1;
     a.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
     m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
 })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'xxxxxx.com');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
```

How are they able to run `ga()`? As far as I can tell they are creating a global func with `window['ga']` and pushing the arguments into an array to `window['ga'].q`, but what then? Is that `window['ga']` function called inside analytics.js file? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ga()` is executed because of the self-invoking anonymous function (SAIF) which does exactly that - it invokes or executes itself after being defined, with the arguments as provided in the parameters at the end.

This explains the GA code in detail: http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/understanding-the-google-analytics-tracking-code/